# 時系列の凡例のフォーマット (日時表示) を変更したい

Tags: python, pandas

以下を実行して、折れ線グラフを生成しました。
凡例の中の時間 YYYY-MM-DD のフォーマット（日付のみ、時間なし）にしたいなら、どこを直せばいですか？

```
for i in range(0,10) :
    df04.plot(figsize=(8, 6))
    plt.legend(loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1))
    plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain',axis='y')
    plt.savefig(fig_name, bbox_inches="tight", pad_inches=0.25) 
    plt.close()
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: `df04` のカラム(`df04.columns`)が `datetime` 型のインスタンスであれば、for ループの直前で、`df04.columns = df04.columns.date` とします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

御質問へのコメントを参考にさせていただき，手持ちの類似データで

```
# plt.legend(loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1))
plt.legend(labels=df04.columns.date,
           loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1))
```

を試したところ所望の結果は得られたのですが，[matplotlib.pyplot.legend](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html) によると（プロット要素との暗黙の対応でラベルを付ける）この形式は非推奨のようです。そこで，ラベルを取り出して加工する記述例と（類似データの）描画結果を示します。

```
ax = df04.plot(figsize=(8, 6))
hndls, lbls = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
lbls = [s.split()[0] for s in lbls]  # YYYY-MM-DD
# lbls = [s.split()[0][5:] for s in lbls]  # MM-DD
ax.legend(handles=hndls, labels=lbls,
          loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1))
ax.ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='y')
plt.savefig(fig_name, bbox_inches="tight", pad_inches=0.25)
plt.close()
```

[image: 描画結果]